# Configure Apache2 sites path

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4

I don't understand `Directory` and `VirtualHost` directives very well as I see it. I want to configure the apache server for the following behavior :

Site content is at : `/var/www/mywebsite`

I want the following resolutions :
`mywebsite.com/` -> `/var/www/mywebsite/index.html`
`mywebsite.com/mywebsite` -> `/var/www/mywebsite/index.html`

I also have php5 install so I could write a simple redirect at `/var/www/redirect.php`. I don't think that this is the right solution however and I'm not sure on what to search to find answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rewrite rules via .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mywebsite/?
RewriteRule (.*) /index.html [R=301,L]
```

> I've been told that htaccess is evil and that I should use the Directory directive instead.

Just move rules to the virtual host section

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@example.net
   ServerName mywebsite.com

   DocumentRoot /vhosts/mywebsite.com/public_html

   <Directory /vhosts/mywebsite.com/public_html>
      Options -Indexes
      AllowOverride All
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from All
      Require All granted

      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mywebsite/?
      RewriteRule (.*) /index.html [R=301,L]
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I've been told that htaccess is evil and that I should use the Directory directive instead. Do you know the equivalent? Also should I modify VirtualHost and Directory in any other way? Currently I get forbidden errors when using Rewrite[Cond|Rule] inside Directory with RewriteEngine On outside